# iterate through list while looking for matching elements from a different list in python

Tags: python, string, list

I have a list of some random strings ex:

`list_test = ["adam", "adam", "lori", "conrad", "lori", "adam"]`

Then i also have two lists, one that i want to test for matches agains and one that will determine what to replace items with.

```
sReplace = ["adam", "lori"]
sReplaceWith = ["carol", "robert"]
```

what i want to do is search list_test if any item on that list matches any item in sReplace if it does replace it with item from sReplaceWith from a matching index number ex.

```
final_list = ["carol", "carol", "robert", "conrad", "robert", "carol"]
```

Any idea how one would do that?

Answer (score 4):

I'd make a dictionary with the Replace as the key and the ReplaceWith as the value.

```
replacements = dict(zip(sReplace, sReplaceWith))

>>> replacements
{'adam': 'carol', 'lori': 'robert'}
```

Then in a list comprehension, you can use `get`, which will look up the replacement from the dictionary, and if not present will use the original word.

```
final_list = [replacements.get(i,i) for i in list_test]

>>> final_list
['carol', 'carol', 'robert', 'conrad', 'robert', 'carol']
```

Comment: Cyber i like this approach but for some reason the compiler that I am using is not able to handle Dictionaries. Can this be done without dictionaries? It's really a limitation of the platform that I am working with and nothing wrong with your idea. thank you!

Comment: @konrad what compiler are you using that doesn't allow dicts?  Dicts have been around from the beginning of python.

Comment: i know this is strange but its a plug in for a design software called revit. i submitted that bug to github a while ago and i am still waiting for a fix.

Answer (score 2):

```
list_test = ["adam", "adam", "lori", "conrad", "lori", "adam"]
sReplace = ["adam", "lori"]
sReplaceWith = ["carol", "robert"]

print([sReplaceWith[sReplace.index(x)] if x in sReplace else x for x in list_test ])
['carol', 'carol', 'robert', 'conrad', 'robert', 'carol']
```

Add the element at the corresponding index with  `sReplaceWith[sReplace.index(x)]` if `x` is in the to be replaced list or else just add `x` to the list

Answer (score 0):

Done without dictionaries:

```
list_test = ["adam", "adam", "lori", "conrad", "lori", "adam"]
sReplace = ["adam", "lori"]
sReplaceWith = ["carol", "robert"]
for list_index in range(0, len(list_test)):
    list_item = list_test[list_index]
    if list_item in sReplace:
        replace_with = sReplaceWith[sReplace.index(list_item)]
        list_test[list_index] = replace_with
print list_test
```

Output:

['carol', 'carol', 'robert', 'conrad', 'robert', 'carol']